# Rails: JSON params are nil when HTML are fine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, forms, controller, parameters

I've just started to work with Rails. I've controller with login code:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def login_attempt
  authorized_user = User.authenticate(params[:username_or_email],params[:login_password])
 ...
```

When I login from HTML form (POST /login_attempt) the same server params[...] return correct value.
If I send POST request from RestKit (POST /login_attempt.json) from XCode in JSON format, it returns nil for params[..].

Question: is there any special coding I need to do? Idea is to create one controller and use it in RESTful
l manner from Rails views and external apps as well.

Comment: 'login_attempt' method should be called 'create' in order to be more RESTful and please, show the part of log which is generated for your request from Xcode